# OCSP stapling cb called before having certificate

Tags: c++, openssl, ocsp

I did a client programs that sends status request in Client hello and verifies the Stapled OCSP response.
For some reason, in several site (Facebook for example) the OCSP stapling cb is being called before having the certificate.
what I see is that I receive ServerHello message, and immediately the cb is being called, before the server send Certificate message.
Did anyone had the same issue? Why does it happen and how do I fix it?

Thanks

Update: it happens only in openssl version 1.0.2 in 1.1.0 it works fine.

Comment: you added the tag `c++` so I was hoping to see some code... :-/

Comment: not much to see really
this is the registration for the cb 
SSL_CTX_set_tlsext_status_cb(ctx, cb);
before the handshake i do SSL_set_tlsext_status_type(ssl, TLSEXT_STATUSTYPE_ocsp)